# Writing $\frac{8r-8s}{2r^{2}-2rs} + \frac{3r^{2}}{rs-r}$ as a single fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Where am I going wrong with this?

$\frac{8r-8s}{2r^{2}-2rs} + \frac{3r^{2}}{rs-r}$

Removing the common factor $2$ in the first expression and $r$ in the second.

$\frac{4r-4s}{r^{2}-rs} + \frac{3r}{s-1}$

I'm not entirely sure how to get a common denominator from here. Do i simply multiply the denominators at this point, if so i get.

$r^{2}s-r^{2}-rs^{2}+rs \therefore r(rs-r-s^{2}+s)$

Now for the first expression, factoring the $r$ gives.

$\frac{4r-4s}{r(r-s)}$

From this point onwards, I'm confused as to how to arrive at common denominator for these expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $$\frac{8(r-s)}{2r(r-s)}+\frac{3r^2}{r(s-1)}$$
And this is $$\frac{4(s-1)+3r^2}{r(s-1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You may further reduce the first term $\frac{4r-4s}{r(r-s)}=\frac{4(r-s)}{r(r-s)}=\frac4r$,

$$\frac{4r-4s}{r^{2}-rs} + \frac{3r}{s-1}=\frac{4}{r} + \frac{3r}{s-r}= \frac{4s-4r+3r^2}{r(s-r)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Start by completely factoring all the numerators and denominators.
\begin{align*}
8r - 8s &= 8(r-s)  \text{,}  \\
2r^2 - 2rs &= 2r(r-s)  \text{,}  \\
3 r^2 &= 3r^2  \text{, and}  \\
rs-r &= -r(r-s)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So you have 
$$  \frac{8r-8s}{2r^2 - 2 r s} + \frac{3r^2}{rs - r}  =  \frac{8(r-s)}{2r(r-s)} + \frac{3r^2}{-r(r-s)}  \text{.}  $$

Now list the factors of the denominators, together with the largest power that the factor appears in either denominator.

\begin{array}{r|l}
\text{factor} & \text{power}  \\ \hline
2 & 1  \\
r & 1  \\
(r-s) & 1  \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}

The product of these factors each raised to its listed power is the least common multiple of both denominators.  In this case, we get $-2r(r-s)$ as the common denominator for these two fractions.  We can also read off by which "fancy form of one" we multiply each fraction to get it in this form.  \begin{align*}
&\frac{8(r-s)}{2r(r-s)} \cdot \frac{-1}{-1} + \frac{3r^2}{-r(r-s)} \cdot \frac{2}{2}  \\  &\qquad{}= \frac{-8(r-s)}{-2r(r-s)} + \frac{6r^2}{-2r(r-s)}    \\  
&\qquad{}= \frac{6r^2 - 8(r-s)}{-2r(r-s)}  \text{.}  \end{align*}

(There are a few simplification which can be applied from here, but you have not asked about those.)